# sum () command not return the added value from table

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I want to sum amount value in the income table where a date is been entered from a textbox.

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;            
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(amount) from income where date='" + TextBox15.Text + "'", con);
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        TextBox16.Text = (myReader["amount"].ToString());
    } 
    con.Close();

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    Label1.Text = e1.Message;
}
```

My amount data type is decimal

Comment: injection attack tastic

Comment: what if the date the user entered was "`; DROP TABLE income; GO`"

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason to use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352798%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your case. Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which is exactly you need because your query returns only one column with one row.

> Executes the query, and **returns the first column of the first row** in
>   the result set returned by the query.

And you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

For example;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(amount) from income where date = @date", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBox15.Text);
TextBox16.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all user parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

There is no column `amount` in your result, either add alias to your aggregation result or just return first value from reader.

```
try
{ 
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader myReader = null;

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(amount) from income where date = @date", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBox15.Text);

   myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   if (myReader.Read())
   {
       TextBox16.Text =myReader[0].ToString();
   }

   con.Close();

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
   Label1.Text = e1.Message;
}
```

Also change `while` to `if` because only one result will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**  there is no column `amount`.
so use alias as below:

Example:

```
select sum(amount) as totalamount from income where date=@datevalue
```

=>to avoid sql injection attacks use parameterised queries:

**Complete Solution:**  Change You code as below:

```
try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader myReader = null;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(amount) as totalamount from income where date=@datevalue", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datevalue", TextBox15.Text));
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            TextBox16.Text = (myReader["totalamount"].ToString());
        } 
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Label1.Text = e1.Message;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do this:

```
try
{ 
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select isnull(sum(amount),0) from income where date = @date", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TextBox15.Text);

   TextBox16.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

   con.Close();

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
   Label1.Text = e1.Message;
}
```

If you can find the time, try giving your objects some reasonable name, quite unlike `TextBox16` ...